# Creating an App using a camera for Android

Tags: android, plugins, camera

I am an aspiring developer trying to create an app. I have seem to come to a brick wall. I am creating the app for the Android Market, mainly because I don't own a Mac or I would create for both iOS and Android. I can't seem to figure out what plug-in to use to make a camera. This is probably something simple and I am overlooking something. But I want to be able to click the row/button and the camera turn on. Then once a photo is taken, it directs to another page for options to do with that photo. Is this possible or is it wishful thinking? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

You have to open the camera, then maybe when the user clicks, call

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // do something with this picture...
        startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, I've just created a camera-app ;)

Comment: How is your app? I'm new to this world but always found it interesting.

Comment: It's a small time-lapse app.